# Can update field only once in GAE Datastore using Objectify

Tags: java, gwt, google-cloud-datastore, requestfactory, objectify

I am serializing Diagram class to GAE Datastore using Objectify. I can update (serialize) all the fields as many times as I want, except Integer arrowTypeId, that is only updated once, and after that **keeps always the same value**. If I leave the app and run it again, I can update again that value, but only once.

To update arroyTypeId I am calling sendDatabaseUpdateDiagramArrows(). This is what happens:

1. I call sendDatabaseUpdateDiagramArrows() with value 1
2. I set that value to the DiagramProxy.setArrowTypeId().
3. As a test, I change the diagram title to DiagramProxy.getArrowTypeId()
4. I call save()
5. On the DAO save(), the **wrong value of ArrowTypeId is received (keeps the old one)**, but **surprisingly, the Title has the right ArrowTypeId stored from step 3)**
6. Changes are serialized with this problem. No exceptions are displayed.

   - Note that I am able to update ArrowTypeId value the first time, from default value 1 to 2. Buth the next time keeps always value 2.
   - Edit: If I change arrowTypeId to a String, I have the same issue.

**DatabaseUtils.java**

```
public static DiagramProxy sendDatabaseUpdateDiagramArrows(DialectiveRequestFactory requestFactory, Integer value, DiagramProxy cellDiagramProxy)
{
    DiagramRequest diagramRequest = requestFactory.diagramRequest();
    DiagramProxy newDiagramProxy = diagramRequest.edit(cellDiagramProxy);
    Date date = new Date();

    newDiagramProxy.setArrowTypeId(value);
    newDiagramProxy.setTitle(Integer.toString(newDiagramProxy.getArrowTypeId()));
    diagramRequest.save(newDiagramProxy).fire();

    return cellDiagramProxy;
}
```

**Diagram.java**

```
@Entity
public class Diagram extends DatastoreObject{


@Indexed private String diagramId;
    private String title;
    private Integer arrowTypeId;

    public String get_id() {
        return diagramId;
    }
    public void set_id(String diagramId) {
        this.diagramId = diagramId;
    }
    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }
    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }
    public Integer getArrowTypeId() {
        return arrowTypeId;
    }
    public void setArrowTypeId(Integer arrowTypeId) {
        this.arrowTypeId = arrowTypeId;
    }
}
```

**DiagramProxy.java**

```
@ProxyFor(value = Diagram.class, locator = ObjectifyLocator.class)
public interface DiagramProxy extends EntityProxy{
    void set_id(String id);
    void setTitle(String title);
    void setArrowTypeId(Integer arrowTypeId);
    Integer getArrowTypeId();
    String get_id();
    String getTitle();
}
```

**DiagramDao.java**

```
public class DiagramDao extends ObjectifyDao<Diagram>{

    public void save(Diagram diagram)
    {
        this.put(diagram);
    } }
```

Comment: Try to remove the`@Indexed` anotation and place `@Id` instead on `diagramId`

Comment: I removed @Indexed and it doesn't make a difference (error persists). I could not add the '@Id' because I am extending Datastore, where there are '@Id' id and version. So just think of diagramId as a normal String, not the primary key, but I am using it for queries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me guess :) as I don't have experience with GAE datastore.

I don't get the point, why you make

```
@Indexed private String diagramId;
```

but getter and setter with non-standard names:

```
public String get_id() {
    return diagramId;
}
public void set_id(String diagramId) {
    this.diagramId = diagramId;
}
```

I'd rather go for:

```
@Indexed private String diagramId;
public String getDiagramId() {
        return diagramId;
    }
    public void setDiagramId(String diagramId) {
        this.diagramId = diagramId;
    }
```

One more thing is that `DiagramRequest` code has not been published, maybe that could help in seeing the problem.